# White screen issue flutter web

Tags: flutter

Flutter 2.0 working good and i successfully run web app by calling

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

but when generated build using `flutter build web`  it build successfully but the output is not working in web browser. it is showing white screen only

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed by changing  `<base href="/">` to  `<base href="./">`
Similar problem occurred in angular 2 beginning time

Comment: Changed it, but did not help unfortunately. It's only a white screen on iOS for me, not sure what's going on.

Comment: same here.. any fix?